# Finding the mantissa from binary with floating point numbers?

Tags: computer-science, binary, floating-point

Here is the example problem slide I am working with:

[image: slide with task]

I understand how to get the exponent, its just 2+128=130-127=3

I understand the first bit is the sign bit for positive or negative.

I just get lost with the mantissa. I know each mantissa has to have a 1 before the decimal, but I'm unsure where the .75 came from. 1100000000000000000000 isn't 75 in decimal I mean right?

How do I calculate the mantissa with floating point numbers in binary?

Answer (score 5):

The number after "." is calculated by 
$$\frac1{2^n}$$
instead of
$$2^n$$
So
$$1.11 = 2^0 + (1/2^1) + (1/2^2)$$
$$= 1 + 0.5 + 0.25$$
$$=1.75$$

Answer (score 2):

[Received answer from /u/empire539 on Reddit.](https://www.reddit.com/r/HomeworkHelp/comments/3p4dy0/computer_architectureorganization_calculating/cw30690)

> Yes, there is an implicitly "hidden" bit, so if your mantissa is
>   1100000000000000000000, then that corresponds to the base 2 number
>   1.11.
>
> Now, if you want to compute the value of .11 part, you just do the
>   same thing as you would do to convert a normal binary number to
>   decimal: multiply each bit by a power of 2.
>
> So, for example, if you wanted to convert the number 1010.1 to
>   decimal, you would do:
>   $1(2^3) + 0(2^2) + 1(2^1) + 0(2^0) + 1(2^{-1}) 
>  = 8 + 2 + 1/2
>  = 10.5$

Comment: Please add your own (partial) answer to the question and update what the question in question now is.